# How to remove axes and grid lines through style in highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I really want to hide Axes and Grid Lines through style in highchart.

I have checked to use the class name attributes in highchart. But which is not working in 4.1.7 version.

can anyone say how can i achieve the above?

Comment: I don't want to use the visible property for Axes, gridLineWidth and gridLineColor for Grid Lines.

Comment: All of options you can hide by parameters: http://jsfiddle.net/tythfwc3/

Comment: You can also use labelGroup, gridGroup and axisGroup for hiding your axes and gridLines: http://jsfiddle.net/3jz56kh2/

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**: Added code example

In Highcharts 5 there is a "styled" version: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

```
.highcharts-grid-line {
    stroke-width: 0;
}
.highcharts-axis-line {
    stroke-width: 0;
}
.highcharts-tick {
    stroke-width: 0;
}
.highcharts-minor-grid-line {
    stroke-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ya your right. But in my concern is to get solution highchart around 4.2 version. Is there any way to achieve the above as i asked?

Comment: You don't want to use the built-in API-properties, you don't want to use the CSS version - Why?